# Find words in double brackets and add a character

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to match any words contained between double brackets and add an extra character (using Notepad++ or EmEditor). For example the following text:

```
[[test]], look at my [[test|testing]] how it tests; I have a [[test]],you know a [[test, and more test]] and [[there's another test you know]]
```

Should become

```
[[test한]], look at my [[test한|testing한]] how it tests; I have a [[test한]],you know a [[test한, and한 more한 test한]] and [[there한's한 another한 test한 you한 know한]]
```

So far I can only match the full content: `\[\[.*?\]\]`

Comment: Try `(?:\G(?!\A)|\[\[)(?:(?!\[\[|]]).)*?\K\w+` and replace with `$0한`

Comment: Might suffice to use a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): [`\w++\K(?=[^][]*]])`](https://regex101.com/r/CL91Q7/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What does `(?!\A)` do in the first branch of the first group? As I understand, `\G` matches either the end of the last match or the start of the whole string, both of which can't be followed by (yet another) start of the string. Is this some kind of trick that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Ah, get it: It's just to prevent `\G` from matching the start of string. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A strict regex version will be

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\[\[)(?:(?!\[\[|]]).)*?\K\w+(?=.*?]])
```

This regex finds any one or more word characters only inside `[[` and `]]`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HBLFnx/4).

A less stricter pattern will be

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\[\[)(?:(?!\[\[|]]).)*?\K\w+
```

Note the missing lookahead at the end. This regex finds any one or more word characters only inside `[[` and `]]` or just between `[[` and end of the string.
See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HBLFnx/5).

If your text contains only well balanced brackets, you may go for a regex that will match any word before any zero or more chars other than brackets followed with `]]`:

```
\w+(?=[^][]*]])
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HBLFnx/6).

The replacement will be `$0한` in all three cases where `$0` represents the whole match value.

**Pattern details**

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|\[\[)` - either the end of the preceding match (`(?!\A)` excludes start of string position from `\G`) or `[[`
- `(?:(?!\[\[|]]).)*?` - any one char (other than line break chars if *`.` matches newline* is OFF, else including newlines), zero or more but as few as possible occurrences, that is not the starting point for `[[` or `]]` char sequences (thus, matching is done only between `[[` and `]]` but this alone does not require `]]` to be right there)
- `\K` - a match reset operator that discards the text matched so far from the overall match value
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(?=.*?]])` - a positive lookahead that requires zero or more chars other than line break chars (if *`.` matches newline* option is OFF, else including newlines) as few as possible and then `]]`.